# 'Bad File Descriptor' in Perl using module 'Digest'

Tags: perl, module, crc, digest, crc32

I am trying to implement Perl digest for CRC, but unfortunately I am getting:

> Digest Read failed: Bad File Descriptor

How do I fix this problem?

This is the module sample code [here](http://search.cpan.org/~olimaul/Digest-CRC-0.18/lib/Digest/CRC.pm):

```
sub crc3439() {
    $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(type=>"crc16");
    $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(width=>16, init=>0x2345, xorout=>0x0000,
                            refout=>1, poly=>0x8005, refin=>1, cont=>1);

    my  $binfile = 'envbin.bin';
    open(fhbin, '>', $binfile) or die "Could not open bin file '$binfile' $!";
    binmode(fhbin);

    $ctx->add($binfile);
    $ctx->addfile(*binfile);
    $digest = $ctx->hexdigest;
    return $digest;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to a) overwrite `$binfile` instead of read it, and b) using `*binfile` as the filehandle instead of `*fhbin`.

Comment: @JimDavis tried  $ctx->addfile(*fhbin); .its throwing same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're overwriting `$binfile` instead of reading it.  Changing the open mode to `'<'` should fix that.

Your `->addfile` is adding a file handle that doesn't exist; you probably want `*fhbin` there, or a lexical (`my $fhbin`) file handle instead.

Also, you overwrite `$ctx` with the extra `->new` call.

```
sub crc3439 {
    my $binfile = shift;

    my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(
        type   => "crc16",
        width  => 16,
        init   => 0x2345,
        xorout => 0x0000,
        refout => 1,
        poly   => 0x8005,
        refin  => 1,
        cont   => 1,
    );

    open(my $fhbin, '<', $binfile) or die "Could not open bin file '$binfile' $!";
    binmode($fhbin);

    $ctx->add($binfile);
    $ctx->addfile($fhbin);

    return $ctx->hexdigest;
}


print crc3439('foo.bin');
```

Comment: @thank u but its giving hex value something like 000007

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: Should i add binary value?

Comment: Then you probably want to change `type` to `crc32` and `width` to `32`, and maybe remove the rest of the options to `Digest::CRC->new` because it looks like you just copied them from the module's synopsis.  If you don't want a hex digest, change it to return `$ctx->digest` instead.

Comment: ya digest code is seems ok for me ,How to check the code in online? how its different from hex digest? could u tell me?